# Best Function and File Format for Saving and Retrieving a Cell Array from a File in Octave

Tags: octave, cell-array

What would be the most performant function (scanf, fscanf, load, textread) and file format (dat, mat, txt, csv) combination to read a file in Octave that contains a cell array?

And which function should I use to store the cell array in that file, in the most read-performant format defined above?

Note that performance is more important for the read operation, since that’s the one I’ll be using the most. But having a performant function to write the files would be desirable too.

Comment: presumably octave's native binary format (which does not have an extension per se), through the `save -binary` and `load -binary` commands.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou The thing is that I don't know how exactly to `save` a file that when read using `load`, produces a cell array (instead of a structure). Can you provide some guidance in that respect?

Comment: if you don't "collect" the result of `load`, it simply unpacks the contents of the binary file onto your workspace. So as long as you know the name of the cell array that is stored in your binary file, you can access it from your workspace as soon as you've "loaded" the file.

Comment: "performance" depends on many factors such as CPU, memory, hard drive throughput and so on. As @TasosPapastylianou answerd using Octaves native bianry format gives good performance in many setups. But for example if you have a slow sd-card (in a RaspberryPi perhaps) you might get better read rate if you use a gzip compressed format. Also the memory footprint is important if you are on an embedded system. So it's up to you to make benchmarks on the target system with "real" data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
octave:1> MyCell = {'a', 'cell', 'with', 5, 'elements'};
octave:2> save -binary myworkspace.dat MyCell
octave:3> clear
octave:4> load -binary myworkspace.dat
octave:5> MyCell 
MyCell = 
{
  [1,1] = a
  [1,2] = cell
  [1,3] = with
  [1,4] =  5
  [1,5] = elements
}
```

or

```
octave:6> S = load ('-binary', 'myworkspace.dat');
octave:7> S.MyCell
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = a
  [1,2] = cell
  [1,3] = with
  [1,4] =  5
  [1,5] = elements
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I was indeed "collecting" the results (or at least I think I was) by using `vocabulary = load('vocabulary.mat');`. After switching to `load('vocabulary.mat', 'vocabulary');` it properly re-generated the vocabulary variable as a cell array. The `-binary` flag didn't make any difference. I save the file using `save('vocabulary.mat', 'vocabulary');`. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: I correct myself on one thing. Binary does indeed make a great difference regarding performance. In some small tests I made, I was able to see an increase in performance of 90% when saving small files and almost 100% when reading them back.

Comment: yes, if you don't specify binary, then the default is human-readable text mode, which clearly would be far less efficient.

Comment: Any comment regarding the difference in behavior when using `vacabulary = load('vocabulary.mat')` vs. using `load('vocabulary.mat', 'vocabulary')`?